# Who is this person and why am being threatened?

Tags: support, status-completed

I have answered several questions on this site (more on cogsci). I have given no medical advice except to see a doctor *now* if I thought it necessary. Yet here are a few comments from a comment thread I had today to an answer about a *cartoon character* [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21327/):

> -Thou shalt not advertise thy work in medicine lest someone judge thine post as advice –  caseyr547 10 hours ago
>   ---- @caseyr547 - There are many people who can be exposed to patients, including doctors, nurses, nurses' aides, etc. I deny any label given me. –  anongoodnurse 23 mins ago
>   - actually you would be liable because you label yourself nurse and so could be sued for practicing. –  caseyr547 14 mins ago
>   ---- @caseyr547 - I haven't labeled myself a nurse! I said a lot of different people can "see" patients in the ER. And I have prescribed nothing. Cut me a break. Anon, good nurse! is a line from Romeo and Juliette. and who would follow the advice of a *non-good* nurse? –  anongoodnurse 10 mins ago
>   - @anongoodnurse you're splitting hairs one ***which will cost you your license or job and if you give bad advice here or on cogsci (especially about those particularly ill) i will see to it that it will.*** –  caseyr547 8 mins ago
>   ---- @caseyr547 - Bullshit. Are you a jealous person? Do you actually think you can come after me and destroy me for advice I give on the internet when I so carefully: 1) give good advice and 2) Qualify it and refer to experts? Who are you, anyway, to be so petty? –  anongoodnurse 4 mins ago
>   - @anongoodnurse jealous no. zealous yes. i dont care what you think your doing its malpractice. –  caseyr547 2 mins ago

What's the problem here? Is there something I don't know about the answers I'm giving on this site? If there is, I'd appreciate hearing from a mod.

Comment: I recognise that name from many disputes on other SE sites. I wouldn't pay him much heed if I were you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I removed the entire conversation already as I don't think the comments were appropriate. You can find a bit more on my stance on the subject [in this meta post from the opposite perspective](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/lets-not-play-doctor).

In short, I don't see any problem with having "nurse" in the name, and I don't see any medical advice in the answer. There is no problem here in my opinion. As a site we essentially disallowed questions that ask for medical advice. I think that is sufficient and I don't see any need to do more here.

We moderators also don't decide any legal issues, we're not qualified to do that. We enforce rules based on legal issues (e.g. users below 13 are not allowed to use the site) if SE asks us to, but not more.

If you receive any more comments of that kind, just flag for moderator attention and we'll deal with it.

Comment: Additionally question which ask for personal advice are usually flagged and closed pretty fast. So don't worry about it. Especially not about some users which have a strange attitude (to say at least).